# How to recursively compile less/sass files with grunt

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, less

I've got project with complex files structure, where there are modules with their own css/less/sass folders.

I want grunt to watch all of them and compile them to target file by replacing last lass/sass folder with css. Examples of files compiled

```
root/less/style.less -> root/css/style.css
```

or

```
root/modules/mymodule/sass/file.sass -> root/modules/mymodule/css/file.css
```

My gruntfile now is:

```
    less: {
        development: {
            options: {
                paths: ["**/*"]
            },
            //files: {"css/main.css": "less/main.less"},
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: "**/*",
                    src: ["**/*.less"],
                    dest: "",
                    ext: ".css"
                }
            ]
        }
        // ,
        // production: {
        //     options: {
        //         paths: ["assets/css"],
        //         cleancss: true
        //     },
        //     files: {"path/to/result.css": "path/to/source.less"}
        // }
    },
    watch: {
      styles: {
        files: ['less/**/*.less'], // which files to watch
        tasks: ['less'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    }
});
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your start up (`cwd`) and destination (`dest`) paths that are incorrect.  Try this:

```
less: {
    development: {            
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: "root", // The startup directory
                src: ["**/*.less"],
                dest: "root", // Destination
                ext: ".css"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: It's not working the way I want it to. My project have a lot of less folders in different folders of project with .less files in it. I want each of such 'less' folder to have sibling 'css' folder with preserved folder structure inside that is the same as it's sibling 'less' file has. Your code creates .css files in same folder as .less files and it also try to compile all files - including those that are imported by other files.